# ImageMagick: how to batch combine multiple TIFF file to a single TIFF file in a directory?

Tags: imagemagick, batch-processing, tiff, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I have 600 TIFF files in a directory, c:\temp.

The file names are like:

```
001_1.tif,
001_2.tif,
001_3.tif

002_1.tif,
002_2.tif,
002_3.tif
....
....
200_1.tif,
200_2.tif,
200_3.tif
```

The combined files should be placed in same directory and the files should be named like:

```
1_merged.tif
2_merged.tif
.....
.....
200_merged.tif
```

I am looking for any single command-line /batch-file to do so through ImageMagick `convert`/ `mogrify` command or any other command/tools.

Please note the overall time taken should not be more than 5 second.

Comment: How are they supposed to be combined - on top of each other, above and below, or beside? The time taken will depend on the size and number of your input images and what hardware you are using.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to combine the 600 single-page TIFFs into one single multi-page TIFF (per set of 3), it is as simple as:

```
 convert  001_*.tiff  1_merged.tiff
 convert  002_*.tiff  2_merged.tiff
 [....]
 convert  200_*.tiff  200_merged.tiff
```

Please note that nobody will be able to guarantee any timing/performance benchmarks... least while we don't even have any idea how exactly your input TIFFs are constituted.  *(Are they 10000x10000 pixels or are they 20x20 pixels?, Are they color or grayscale?, etc.pp.)*

This is different from Mark's answer, because he seems to have assumed you want to combine the input files all into a 1-page image, where the originals are tiled across a larger page...

Answer (score 2):

This should do it - I will leave you to do error checking in case you haven't actually got all the images you suggest!

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,200) DO (
   set "formattedValue=000000%%A"
   set "x=!formattedValue:~-3!"
   convert !x!_*.tif +append !x!_merged.tif
   echo !x!
)
```

So, if your images look like this

001_1.tif

[image]

001_2.tif

[image]

001_3.tif

[image]

you will get this in `merged_001.tif`

[image]

If you change `+append` to `-append` then `merged_001.tif` will be like this:

[image]

If you remove `+append` altogether, you will get 200 multi-page TIFs with 3 pages each - same as Kurt's answer.

Comment: Thanks Mark.It worked with slight variation -adjoin instead of -append to get multi-page tif image.But it took me ~30 sec to process.I have tested on Windows 7- Intel(R) core(TM) i3 CPU 550 @3.20 GHZ ,Ram 4 GB.My file sizes are ..1.tf-> ~270 KB, ..2.tf-> ~16 KB, ..3.tif->10 KB.Is there any workaround to achieve this within 5-10 second ? Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You can try pre-pending `start /b` in front of `convert` so that the 200 `convert` processes run in parallel - not sure how well windows will handle that though - maybe experiment with 4 parallel converts initially. Or maybe add a parameter to the script of `start` and `end` number, then run one with `1-50` a second with `51-100` and so on all 4 in parallel.