# batch combine multiple tif in a directory

Tags: imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, gnu-parallel, im4java

I have 200x3 tif files in a folder which is to to be combined in multi-page tif files like

1_1.tif,1_2.tif,1_3.tif-->1_m.tif

2_1.tif,2_2.tif,2_3.tif-->2_m.tif

..........

200_1.tif,200_2.tif,200_3.tif-->200_m.tif

Can i have a command line solution like "gm benchmark mogrify -format tif *.jepg"?

what would be gm4java alternative ?

Currently my convert opration through JAI is taking ~27s, can it be reduced to ~2-3s ?
I am testing on WIN 7,Intel core i3 CPU 550 @3.2Hz (2 core).
Please do help ..

Comment: Did you try running 4 tasks in parallel like I suggested http://stackoverflow.com/a/30620870/2836621

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel and ImageMagick's convert you can run:

```
parallel convert -adjoin {} {= s/_1/_2/ =} {= s/_1/_3/ =} {= s/_1/_m/ =} ::: *_1.tif
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel